# Style dropdown ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to ruby on rails. I have the problem that I can not apply the style to the following code:

"<%= select(:pais, :codigo, Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.country, p.code ] }) %>"

I'm using metro-bootstrap and apply this in particular I want the "form-control" but not working class. The rest of the stuff if you apply the class, but not in this code. probe in several ways, which do not generate the error but does nothing is this

"<%= select(:pais, :codigo, Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.country, p.code ] }, :class => "form-control") %>"

but does not apply the style

Answer (score 1):

You need separate option like :

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Do as below:

```
<%= select(:pais,
           :codigo,
           Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.country, p.code ] },
           { :class => "form-control" }) %>
```

And read documentation carefully [Form Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)